# Looping through a list of dictionaries, defining and saving the variables for use outside the loop in other functions

Tags: python, dictionary, scope

I have a list of dictionaries

```
list = [{"name":"Jane", "age":27, "address":"aaaaa"}, {"name":"Mike", "age":28,"address":"aaasdf"}]
for x in list:
   name = x['name']
   age= x['age']
   address=x['address']
```

I want to use the defined variables in a number of other functions, where I can pass name, age, address, as parameters.

I am not sure how to do this as due to the scope , only the last value from the loop is saved.
I am new to coding and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you consider building a list of names, ages and addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just call the functions within the loop, like so:

```
def my_function(name, age, address):
    print(f"Name: {name}, age: {age}, address: {address}")

list = [{'name': 'Jane', 'age': 27, 'address': 'aaaaa'}, {'name': 'Mike'
        , 'age': 28, 'address': 'aaasdf'}]

for x in list:
    name = x['name']
    age = x['age']
    address = x['address']
    my_function(name, age, address)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get only the values of the last iteration is because you overwrite your variables on each iteration.

Explaining further into this, let's say you only want the `name`.

If you simply add a print **inside** the loop you are going to see that you variable actually gets the correct value at some point:

```
myList = [{"name": "Jane", "age": 27, "address": "aaaaa"}, {"name": "Mike", "age": 28, "address": "aaasdf"}]
for x in myList:
   name = x['name']
   print(name)
```

This will output:

```
Jane
Mike
```

The problem you are facing is because you try to access the variable outside of your loop like:

```
myList = [{"name": "Jane", "age": 27, "address": "aaaaa"}, {"name": "Mike", "age": 28, "address": "aaasdf"}]
for x in myList:
   name = x['name']
print(name)
```

This will output only `Mike` since `Jane` is overwritten.

Now to your question since you have a function that you want to use the values of your dictionary you have to call the function the same way i used my `print` to explain it.

So your code should look something like:

```
myList = [{"name": "Jane", "age": 27, "address": "aaaaa"}, {"name": "Mike", "age": 28, "address": "aaasdf"}]
for x in myList:
   name = x['name']
   age = x['age']
   address = x['address']
   a_test_function(name, age, address)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I want to call the function, only for the values of name let say that match certain criteria. Lets for x in myList, if address=='something' only then call function and pass the correct value to it?

Comment: Still you can apply all this logic inside the loop. The print i was using was to explain how your variables behave. Now you can apply your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the functions for every dictionaries values you could do something like this:

```
list = [{"name":"Jane", "age":27, "address":"aaaaa"}, {"name":"Mike", "age":28,"address":"aaasdf"}]
for x in list:
   name = x['name']
   age= x['age']
   address=x['address']
   some_function(name,age,address)
   some_other_function(name,age,address)
```

You can't use these variables somewhere else to call a function because then you would need to package them up in an array again defeating the purpose of unpacking them here.